# Configure 2 sites in the IIS of windows Server 2016

Tags: iis, asp.net, dns-hosting

It is really urgent that I have to configure a staging site of my web application in Windows Server 2016.

I have ASP.net site which is running smoothly in my win server 2016, and I have configured A record from my bluehost DNS Manager.

**My Question:** I want to add a new site in the IIS of my server using same port. So how I could manage to reach it from A record or CNAME record from bluehost?

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can [set up several sites using the same port](http://woshub.com/run-multiple-websites-on-the-same-port-and-ip-address-on-iis/) in IIS. CNAME records don't handle ports (neither A for that matter). You set that up in IIS. 
I haven't used IIS in a long time, but the link I provided should point you in the right direction.